# Sinatra asset pipeline gem, compiles to an empty .json

Tags: ruby, heroku, sinatra, asset-pipeline, sinatra-assetpack

I'm trying to get [sinatra-asset-pipeline](https://github.com/kalasjocke/sinatra-asset-pipeline) to work for my Sinatra application, so I can get my assets to display on Heroku. I'm following a MVC pattern and is currently storing my assets inside `project-folder/assets/stylesheets/application.scss`. My `config/environment.rb` file contains all the gem requirements:

```
require 'bundler/setup'
Bundler.require
require 'sprockets'
require 'sinatra/activerecord/rake'
require 'sinatra/asset_pipeline/task'
require 'sinatra/asset_pipeline'
require 'sinatra/sprockets-helpers'
require 'rack-flash'
require 'sass/plugin/rack'
require_all 'app'
```

I configure the **sinatra-asset-pipeline** gem inside my `ApplicationController`.

```
require './config/environment'

class ApplicationController < Sinatra::Base
  register Sinatra::Sprockets::Helpers
  register Sinatra::AssetPipeline
  set :sprockets, Sprockets::Environment.new('app')
  set :assets_prefix, '/assets'
  set :digest_assets, true

  configure do
    set :public_folder, 'public'
    set :views, 'app/views'
    sprockets.append_path File.join('app', 'assets', 'stylesheets')
  end

  get '/' do
    erb :'index'
  end

end
```

My **Rakefile** contains the code for running the rake task

```
Sinatra::AssetPipeline::Task.define! ApplicationController
```

When I run `rake assets:precompile --trace` I get:

```
** Invoke assets:precompile (first_time)
** Execute assets:precompile
```

Which creates the folder `/public/assets/.sprockets-manifest-107e377ad857386671d3a9b56a890322.json`. This file is only containing this line of code: `{}`

Answer (score 1):

I had to specify the asset_precompile inside my Controller to get my rake task to compile in the right format: `set :assets_precompile, %w(application.css *.png *.jpg *.svg *.eot *.ttf *.woff *.woff2)` I hope this answer can help anyone else struggling with Sinatra and asset pipeline.

```
class ApplicationController < Sinatra::Base
  register Sinatra::Sprockets::Helpers

  set :assets_precompile, %w(application.css *.png *.jpg *.svg *.eot *.ttf *.woff *.woff2)

  register Sinatra::AssetPipeline
  set :sprockets, Sprockets::Environment.new('app')
  set :assets_prefix, '/assets'
  set :digest_assets, true

  configure do
    set :public_folder, 'public'
    set :views, 'app/views'
    sprockets.append_path File.join('assets', 'stylesheets')
  end

  get '/' do
    erb :'index'
  end

end
```